# Layer Tree and Layer Switcher (OpenLayers and ExtJS)

Tags: openlayers-2, ext-js

Is there any possibility to get only the Base Layers (for example OpenLayers) in the LayerSwitcher and only the Overlays in the LayerTree?

I tried "'displayInLayerSwitcher': false", but with this my Overlays are also missing in the LayerTree.

Comment: Why are you using the openlayers-3 tag? This is about OpenLayers 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using GeoExt as you are talking about a "LayerTree", right?

If yes, just use a OverLay-Layer-Container:
http://geoext.org/lib/GeoExt/widgets/tree/OverlayLayerContainer.html

```
var layerList = [
{
nodeType: "gx_overlaylayercontainer",
text: "Overlay Layers",
expanded: true
}];
var tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
title: "Layer",
loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
applyLoader: false
}),
root: {
children: layerList
},
rootVisible: false
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/x9zrsf17/

and for the OpenLayers-Layerswitcher you could for Example just use display:none für the Overlay-CSS-classes:
http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/pm7ytLcj/

```
.dataLbl, .dataLayersDiv
{
    display:none;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. The CSS-classes were the missing parts in my code.